# How to split spread string inside array

Tags: php

i have array of words and mistakes

```
$words = ["hi", "my", "name", "is", "john doe"];
```

i have loop to trim words

```
foreach ($words as &$w) {
    $w = trim($w);
}
```

but i wanna have final result to be

```
$words ["hi", "my", "name", "is", "john", "doe"];
```

having "john" and "doe" trimmed too

i thought using

```
if (str_contains($w, " ")) {
    $w = explode(" ", $string);
}
```

to clean every word but i do not know how to spread them back and removing old bad value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not easily make one array element become *two* array elements, with that kind of loop. If you don't manipulate the original array by using references, but add the elements to a new result array instead, this will be way easier.

```
$words = ["hi", "my", "name", "is", "john doe"];
$result = [];

foreach($words as $word) {
  $result = array_merge($result, explode(' ', $word));
}
```

https://3v4l.org/bctuK

Of course the whole thing could be done even quicker, if you just joined your existing word array with a space between the elements first, and then exploded the result at space again. One-liner:

```
$words = explode(' ', implode(' ', $words));
```

https://3v4l.org/ERd3l

Answer (score 1):

```
$words = [ 'hi', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'john doe' ];

$result = [];
foreach ($words as $word) {
  array_push($result, ...explode(' ', trim($word)));
}

print_r($result);
```